# Access webserver on host OS through guest on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, ubuntu, localhost, virtualization, virtualbox

I have Splunk running on my host OS (Windows 7) which I can access by going to `http://localhost:8000`. I can also access it by going to `http://(my internal IP 192.something):8000`. I have Lubuntu 13.04 running on VirtualBox and I want to access Splunk through there. I've been trying out the solution mentioned here (https://superuser.com/questions/144453/virtualbox-guest-os-accessing-local-server-on-host-os) but I can't access it. Would I need to forward the port 8000?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Set network adapter in VirtualBox to `Bridged Adapter` mode
- Ensure port 8000 is allowed in windows firewall.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Avoid answering questions that are over a year old. I doubt that the OP is still searching for an answer for this problem.

Comment: anyway, the answer can be helpful for someone else...